# Google Drive Batch request documentation needs to be updated

Tags: google-drive-api

This relates to the documentationf or the batch request - https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/performance#batch-example-request.

Documentation sample:

```
--END_OF_PART
Content-Length: 337
Content-Type: application/http
content-id: 1
content-transfer-encoding: binary



POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions?fields=id
Authorization: Bearer authorization_token
Content-Length: 70
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8



{
  "emailAddress":"example@appsrocks.com",
  "role":"writer",
  "type":"user"
}
--END_OF_PART
```

As of 2 weeks ago (sometime in July 2023), the Google Drive batch API calls from our product stopped working. It keeps erroring out with a HTTP 400 (BAD REQUEST) failure - unable to parse HTTP headers.

We finally traced it back to extra blank lines in the payload.

This works:

```
--END_OF_PART

POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions?fields=id

--END_OF_PART
```

This does not work (2 blank lines, as in the documentation)

```
--END_OF_PART


POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions?fields=id


--END_OF_PART
```

Please update the documentation to reflect this. We spent a couple of days debugging this before we found the issue.

This Curl request works:

````
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=END_OF_PART' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' \
--data '--END_OF_PART

GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<fileid>/permissions

--END_OF_PART--
'```

But this does not:

```curl --location 'https://www.googleapis.com/batch/drive/v3' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=END_OF_PART' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' \
--data '--END_OF_PART


GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<fileid>/permissions


--END_OF_PART--
'```
````

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

From your showing request body, I'm worried about the following modification points.

- The last boundary is not closed. In this case, `--END_OF_PART--` is used instead of `--END_OF_PART`.
- The line breaks might be required to be modified.

When these points are reflected in your request body, how about the following modification?

#### Modified request body:

```
--END_OF_PART
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: 1

POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions?fields=id
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"

{"emailAddress":"example@appsrocks.com","role":"writer","type":"user"}
--END_OF_PART--
```

#### Testing:

When I tested the following curl command, I confirmed that it worked fine.

```bash
curl --location 'https://www.googleapis.com/batch/drive/v3' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=END_OF_PART' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ###' \
--data '--END_OF_PART
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: 1

POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId1}/permissions?fields=id
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"

{"emailAddress":"###","role":"writer","type":"user"}
--END_OF_PART
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: 2

POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId2}/permissions?fields=id
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"

{"emailAddress":"###","role":"writer","type":"user"}
--END_OF_PART--'
```

Or,

```bash
curl --location 'https://www.googleapis.com/batch/drive/v3' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=END_OF_PART' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ###' \
--data-binary "@sample.txt"
```

`sample.txt` is as follows.

```
--END_OF_PART
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: 1

POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId1}/permissions?fields=id
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"

{"emailAddress":"###","role":"writer","type":"user"}
--END_OF_PART
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: 2

POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId2}/permissions?fields=id
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"

{"emailAddress":"###","role":"writer","type":"user"}
--END_OF_PART--
```

#### Reference:

- [Batch details](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/performance#details)

Comment: @KaySubb About `Sounds good to me. Thanks, Tanaike.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

Sounds good to me. Thanks, Tanaike.

Comment: By the way, you posted a comment as an answer. I'm worried that you might have posted it by mistake.